# Since 15.04 Upgrade, Lost my Terminal/Shell

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome, upgrade, 15.04

Since I've upgraded to 15.04 I've lost my terminal. I cannot fall back to using xterm because xterm is simply not as good as the basic Ubuntu terminal!

How do I get it back?

When I click the terminal icon (the launcher) it flashes a bit, as though something were happening, but a launch never happens (ie, I get no terminal)

How do I get it back?

EDIT: I'm a moderate user, but I took the advice to run this through strace ... what I have here is a large pile of robot vomit I can't make sense of.

Due to 30k character posting limit, I've included the latter part of the robot vomit:

```
stat("/usr/bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=98304, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/optparse.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=60346, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/optparse.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=60346, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python3.4/__pycache__/optparse.cpython-34.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51522, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51522, ...}) = 0
brk(0x169d000)                          = 0x169d000
read(4, "\356\f\r\n\326\223\24U\272\353\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 51523) = 51522
read(4, "", 1)                          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4cf947000
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb899b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libglib-2.0.so.0", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libglib-2.0.so.0.so", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libglib-2.0.so.0.la", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libgobject-2.0.so.0", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libgobject-2.0.so.0.so", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libgobject-2.0.so.0.la", 0x7ffeefb8ab00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/repository", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 38 entries */, 32768)    = 1544
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gio-2.0.typelib", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=321828, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 321828, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fe4cf8f8000
close(5)                                = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 53 entries */, 32768)    = 2208
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fe4cf8f8000, 321828)          = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 38 entries */, 32768)    = 1544
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gio-2.0.typelib", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=321828, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 321828, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fe4cf8f8000
close(5)                                = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 53 entries */, 32768)    = 2208
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/GObject-2.0.typelib", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 58576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7fe4d193f000
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8147, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8147, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__pycache__/Gio.cpython-34.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7132, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7132, ...}) = 0
read(4, "\356\f\r\n\346`\"T\323\37\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 7133) = 7132
read(4, "", 1)                          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("libgio-2.0.so.0", 0x7ffeefb8b9b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libgio-2.0.so.0.so", 0x7ffeefb8b9b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("libgio-2.0.so.0.la", 0x7ffeefb8b9b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/repository", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 38 entries */, 32768)    = 1544
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/GObject-2.0.typelib", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 58576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fe4d1930000
close(5)                                = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/girepository-1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 53 entries */, 32768)    = 2208
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fe4d1930000, 58576)           = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GObject.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25714, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GObject.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25714, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__pycache__/GObject.cpython-34.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20023, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20023, ...}) = 0
read(4, "\356\f\r\n\346`\"Trd\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0*\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 20024) = 20023
read(4, "", 1)                          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
brk(0x16c6000)                          = 0x16c6000
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4cf8b8000
munmap(0x7fe4cf8b8000, 262144)          = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 4
write(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffeefb8d3c0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY)          = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4d2f96000
read(5, "sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev"..., 1024) = 1024
read(5, "noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0\ncgro"..., 1024) = 1024
read(5, "29328k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=100"..., 1024) = 295
read(5, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fe4d2f96000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4d2f96000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 5
write(5, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4cf0f7000
mprotect(0x7fe4cf0f7000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fe4cf8f6ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fe4cf8f79d0, tls=0x7fe4cf8f7700, child_tidptr=0x7fe4cf8f79d0) = 6333
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x7fe4d0ac82c0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_NOCLDSTOP, 0x7fe4d2b82d10}, NULL, 8) = 0
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffeefb8ccc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fe4d27dd2f0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe4d2b82d10}, 8) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(6, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/dbus-RSRqJeRsEp"}, 23) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS{pid=6332, uid=1000, gid=1000}}, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 1
sendto(6, "AUTH\r\n", 6, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 6
recvfrom(6, 0x16be800, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(6, "REJECTED EXTERNAL DBUS_COOKIE_SH"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 46
sendto(6, "AUTH EXTERNAL 31303030\r\n", 24, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 24
recvfrom(6, 0x16be800, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(6, "OK 8c7972215808f66f3a43ad2c553d9"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 37
sendto(6, "NEGOTIATE_UNIX_FD\r\n", 19, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 19
recvfrom(6, 0x16be800, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(6, "AGREE_UNIX_FD\r\n", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 15
sendto(6, "BEGIN\r\n", 7, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 7
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 7
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4ce8f6000
mprotect(0x7fe4ce8f6000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fe4cf0f5ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fe4cf0f69d0, tls=0x7fe4cf0f6700, child_tidptr=0x7fe4cf0f69d0) = 6334
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 8
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16c1410, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 8
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
read(8, 0x7ffeefb8cfe0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16c28a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x16be8a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x16b6058, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7fe4d0d90568, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fe4d0d90570, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7fe4d2b6cc00, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
brk(0x16e7000)                          = 0x16e7000
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fe4ce0f5000
mprotect(0x7fe4ce0f5000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fe4ce8f4ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fe4ce8f59d0, tls=0x7fe4ce8f5700, child_tidptr=0x7fe4ce8f59d0) = 6335
futex(0x7fe4d0d90548, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7fe4c0005d00, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC)     = 8
pipe2([9, 10], O_CLOEXEC)               = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fe4d2f8a9d0) = 6336
futex(0x7fe4c4000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
close(10)                               = 0
close(8)                                = 0
read(9, "", 50000)                      = 0
close(9)                                = 0
wait4(6336, 0x7ffeefb8d114, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
futex(0x15b29c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7fe4c4001190, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x16b6158, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x16bf110, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7fe4c4001190, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x16b6158, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6336, si_status=8, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>
```

Comment: Do you still have the "gnome-terminal" package installed?

Comment: Yeah, even when I type `gnome-terminal` into the xterm terminal nothing happens.

Comment: Although it's completely out of my domain, try installing `strace` and running `strace gnome-terminal`. See if there's any detailed output there you might be able to use to debug the issue (it would probably also be helpful to have in your question for additional information).

Comment: Updated. I certainly can't understand that, and I'm not exactly alien to these things.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" when you try to run `gnome-terminal` from `xterm`, do you mean it immediately quits with no output, giving your back a shell in `xterm`? Or do you mean it continues running but never produces a window or any output in `xterm`, so all you see is a cursor at the beginning of a blank line? Or do you mean something else? Also, does GNOME Terminal work when you're logged in as a different user? (You can log in with the Guest account to test this.) When you run GNOME Terminal, are error messages written to `~/.xsession-errors`? (You can [edit] again to give this info.)

Comment: When I click the little black terminal icon (you know the one) it flashes as though it were booting up. ...then nothing. 

Nothing happens is pretty much the complaint. No graphical interface...just dead air.

Comment: As @1Up said: Use `xterm` and run the command `gnome-terminal` in there. Paste the output into your qestion.

Comment: I did paste the output :D thats it up there :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that gtk (or some element of gtk) had to be reinstalled. Something either went out of date or became corrupted with the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome terminal
```

That will remove it (if in fact it is there) and replace it with a fresh copy.